# Bubble Sort dynamic array using functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting, dynamic

I need a program so i can bubble sort a dynamic array filled with random numbers from 1 to 100 using the next functions:
Bubble sort function
Swap function (For bubble sorting)
fill array
and the main function.
I have this code but in dont know why the Bubble sort functionmis not working, please help me.
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define TAM 100
void fill(int vector[]){
    int i;
    srand (time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<=TAM; i++){
        vector[i]= rand()%100+1;
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b){
   int temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
   }   

void bubble (int vector[], int n){
    int c,d,t;

  for (c=0; c<n-1; c++){
    for (d=0 ;d<n-c-1; d++){
      if (vector[d] > vector[d+1]) {
        swap(&vector[d+1], &vector[d+1]);
        /* Swapping */  
        /*t=vector[d];
        vector[d]=vector[d+1]; 
        vector[d+1]=t;*/
      }
    }}}

/*void print (){
    }*/

 int main(void){
    //int vector[];
    int *vector;
    vector = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*TAM);
    if (vector==NULL){
perror("Problemas reservando memoria");
exit (1);
}
fill(vector);
bubble(vector, 100);
printf("%i", vector);


free (vector);
 return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `swap(&vector[d+1], &vector[d+1])` does nothing.

Comment: so what should i do?
now i don't know what i am doing.

Comment: I would start by checking your swap argument indices

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to read your own code, because your mind sees what you wanted to write, and doesn't see what you actually wrote. So you need to look closely at that line. Then ask yourself what you intended that line to do, and what does that line actually do. Of course, I've already told you what the line does. So you need to look closely at the line to see why.

Answer (score 0):

a bubble sort function does not need to refer to any sub functions

Here is a typical bubble sort in C

Note: declare `array[]`, `c`, `d`,`swap` and `n` for the specific characteristics of your data

```
for (c = 0 ; c < n - 1; c++)
{
    for (d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
    {
        if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
        {
            swap       = array[d];
            array[d]   = array[d+1];
            array[d+1] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

sorts of character strings require use of `strcpy()` and `strcmp()` but are effectively the same algorithm